# Strange behaviour of SKPhysicsBody

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In my app I want to create a physics body for a node programmatically. However when I create the physics body programmatically, it doesn't seem to work, although the physics body created in the SpriteKit editor does work. When the physicsbody is created programmatically, it does not collide with another node, when it is created in the editor, it does.

Here is my code:

```
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)

    if let body = self.physicsBody{
        body.isDynamic = true
        body.affectedByGravity = false
        body.allowsRotation = false
        body.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryBitmask.shootWall.rawValue
        body.collisionBitMask = CollisionCategoryBitmask.circle.rawValue
        body.contactTestBitMask = CollisionCategoryBitmask.circle.rawValue
    }
```

size is the size property of the node.

When I now comment out the first line where the physics body is assigned to the node and instead set the physics body in the SpriteKit scene editor it does work. Note that the code inside the if condition is being executed in both cases.

[image]

**Update**:

What is interesting is that when I do this:

```
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [physicsBody!])
```

which shouldn't have any impact because it its basically changing nothing, then it doesn't work as well. Is this a bug in SpriteKit?

Comment: You need to expand your code, I have a feeling you are resetting the body in some way

Comment: If by resetting you mean to set it to nil again then that should not be the case. I set a breakpoint in the scenes upstate method and checked the value of the physics body, it is not nil.

Comment: no you are applying a new generic physicsbody, not the one you created

Comment: But this can only happen in another assignment of the physics body, right?

Comment: yes, check to make sure the body you create is the body that is attached to the sprite

Comment: I couldn't find anywhere where there is another assignment of the physics body. However I found out something interesting. The question is now updated.

Comment: I am not seeing any changes, are you waiting on approval?

Comment: `physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [physicsBody!])` changes your entire body,  the only thing preserved is the path of the body, everything else gets reset to default

Comment: Ok, interesting. So now we know that he issue has to be with some property that is set to the correct value in the scene editor but is not in my code. Do you have any idea which one that might be?

Comment: Can you post your project

Comment: To the public on stack overflow? Sorry, I can't.

Comment: Can you email it to me?

Comment: If you give me your email address, yes, I would

Comment: knight0fdragon@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    factor = 0.5
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.pBody() 

}
```

physicsWorld does not exist yet, so the body does not get placed in the world.

You want to do it after it is created, so throw your code into a closure to be launched after your setup completes.  You can do this using `DispatchQueue`

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    factor = 0.5
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.pBody() //This will fire after the SKS finished building the scene, so physicsWorld will exist
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that works well! But can you maybe explain quickly why the closure is executed after the setup is complete?

Comment: because on the main thread it needs to complete its current process before it can switch to a new task, DispatchQueue throws the closure onto a queue of new tasks that it will grab once the current process finishes.  Basically you are washing dishes, somebody places a new dish into the pile of dishes to be washed, once you finish the current dish you are washing, you can grab the next available dish that needs to be cleaned.